# Connect to MySQL DB using PHP, error 'Using $this when not in object context'

Tags: php

I don't know how to write PHP functions.
I'm getting this error 'Using $this when not in object context'.
I've only inserted the lines 3 and 4 (the MySQL connection code), the rest of the code is fine.
How do I fix these lines?

```
<?php

 $this->connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mbrconsu_un394x', 'y1cz9,rd+hf6') or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db('mbrconsu_mmx', $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT tema FROM treinamentos ORDER BY tema ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$stack=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            array_push($stack,array($row['column1'],$row['column2']));
          }

echo json_encode($stack);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$this` is only used within a class when you want to refer to a property or function of the class you are working inside of.
2. You're not in a class, so replace `$this->connection` with `$connection`.
3. Avoid using mysql_* functions, they are deprecated. You'll be doing yourself a favor by learning either PDO or mySQLi instead.

Comment: Every other answers were helpful, but as Sammitch answered first and has the most complete answer, I'm choosing him.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `$this` outside of an object class, which is what appears to be happening here.  Just rename `$this->connection` to `$connection` in all locations.

Note that you also should not be using `mysql_*` functions at all, as these are deprecated. You might want to use `mysqli_*` functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the keyword "this" and the pointer "->"

```
<?php 

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mbrconsu_un394x', 'y1cz9,rd+hf6') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mbrconsu_mmx', $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT tema FROM treinamentos ORDER BY tema ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$stack=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            array_push($stack,array($row['column1'],$row['column2']));
          }

echo json_encode($stack);

?>
```

Comment: Read the other answers for a more detailed explanation of why!

Answer (score 0):

`$this` has value only inside a defined class. i.e, we generally use it while defining a class to point to a method or property in that class.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'mbrconsu_un394x', 'y1cz9,rd+hf6') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mbrconsu_mmx') or die(mysql_error());;
```

This'll work just fine.

By the way use `mysqli_*` or `pdo` for better results.